# Web3Auth method to enter email Id and get the value of wallet address as return value

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, decentralized-applications, web3auth

Is there any web3Auth method which takes email id as input and returns a wallet address as output ?
The wallet address returned should be real .
By real I mean , if the user logs in with the emailId we get the same address that was our output from the method .

Tried looking for something in the documentation , it is so vast and I have very less time .
Will be grateful if I get any sort of help from here.
Reference : https://web3auth.io/